# multiply symbol in a .sum method Rails gives errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, chartkick

I´m creating this column chart with chartkicks. I´m pretty much stuck and out of options.

```
<div class="col-md-3 chart-box">
      <%= column_chart current_user.transports.map{|t|
      { name: "Co2 flight", data: current_user.transports.group_by_year(:created_at).sum(:transport_flight_km) }} %>
              </div>
```

The problem is that I have to multiply the sum of

```
:transport_flight_km
```

with

```
* 0.1404
```

and show it as one column, for now ( more will be added later). 
I´m unable to make this multiplication and rails throw me various errors depending on where I place my calculation.

if I do it like this

```
<%= column_chart current_user.transports.map{|t|
      { name: "Co2 flight", data: current_user.transports.group_by_year(:created_at).sum(:transport_flight_km * 0.1404) }} %>
```

Rails throw me this Error, which make sense

```
undefined method `*' for :transport_flight_km:Symbol
```

And if I do it like this:

```
<%= column_chart current_user.transports.map{|t|
      { name: "Co2 flight", data: current_user.transports.group_by_year(:created_at).sum(0.1404 * :transport_flight_km )}} %>
```

Rails gives me this error

```
:transport_flight_km can't be coerced into Float
```

And if I do it like this

```
<%= column_chart current_user.transports.map{|t|
      { name: "Co2 flight", data: current_user.transports.group_by_year(:created_at).sum("0.1404" * :transport_flight_km )}} %>
```

I get this Error:

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

Can anyone advise me about how to do this calculation in this line of code?

thanks in advance
Daði

Comment: call a method that returns a numeric value instead of using that symbol. you can't multiply a symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make it a string:

```
.sum("transport_flight_km * 0.1404")
```

Comment: OMG...this is so brilliant and simple, I should have figure that out :) thanks @smathy